# Thinkpad middle button scrolling

Tags: laptop, thinkpad

I'm running Ubuntu on my Thinkpad T60.  Is there a way to get the middle button to act like a scroll like it would when it runs Windows?

I'd like to be able to hold the middle button down and scroll down a webpage using the red button.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://www.eastwoodzhao.com/thinkpad-middle-button-scroll-ubuntu-linux-10-04-lucid-lynx/

In short, run this: `gksu gedit /usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-thinkpad.conf` and put this in the file:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Trackpoint Wheel Emulation"
MatchProduct "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint|DualPoint Stick|Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
Option "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
Option "Emulate3Buttons" "false"
Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
Option "YAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```

Save and restart.

Comment: In 10.10 you should use `gksu gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-thinkpad.conf` instead

Comment: Awesome! Sill accurate on Debian Jessie.

Comment: Worked for me on a T540p running Debian Stretch, but I also had to add ``Driver "evdev"`` to the configuration file.

Answer (score 17):

Install package "gpointing-device-settings"
Set options as follows:

```
check "Use middle button emulation"
check "Use wheel emulation"
select button "2"
check "Enable vertical scroll"
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I can verify that this works on my ThinkPad X60 running Ubuntu 10.04. +1, and use the rep to post your screenshot. :)

Answer (score 4):

ThinkWiki has [instructions](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint) on how to do this. Specifically, how to use [xinput(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/xinput.1.html) to configure the TrackPoint.

(All in all, [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkWiki) is a great resource. It's pretty much the go-to place for just about anything on running Linux on Thinkpads.)

Answer (score 1):

I use the following in my AwesomeWM autostart file:

```
# make the mouse work right on my thinkpad in lucid
xinput set-prop 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint' "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 1
xinput set-prop 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint' "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 2
xinput set-prop 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint' "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" 200
```

In the default Gnome install you could write a script that runs on boot or perhaps check out if the .xinitrc or .Xresources is used. (I can't recall which is used any more)

Answer (score 1):

Gpointing is a graphical application  for the gnome desktop to achieve the same result ;)

With Ubuntu install it in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

or via software center "gpointing-device-settings"

Comment: Worked great for a HP Pavilion touchpad

Comment: `E: Package 'gpointing-device-settings' has no installation candidate
aj07mm@aj07mm-ThinkPad-X220:~$`

Comment: Looks like this gpointing-device-settings is not supported anymore. I couldn't this package.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14.04, these settings are in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-evdev-trackpoint.conf. It looks like this:

```
 # trackpoint users want wheel emulation

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "trackpoint catchall"
    MatchIsPointer  "true"
    MatchProduct    "TrackPoint|DualPoint Stick"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option  "Emulate3Buttons"   "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheel"  "true"
    Option  "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option  "XAxisMapping"  "6 7"
    Option  "YAxisMapping"  "4 5"
EndSection
```

To get "natural scrolling", that is, scrolling in the direction of the pointer, you can swap the YAxisMapping values to be "5 4" instead. I restarted after I swapped mine and it worked fine.