# Is there any way of enabling middle click scrolling?

Tags: mouse-scroll

The issue is similar to this: [Thinkpad middle button scrolling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2557/thinkpad-middle-button-scrolling)

But here, I have an average computer. Basically, when I press the middle button in Windows and move the cursor a little from the starting position the page starts scrolling which is very convenient because I don't have to scroll the wheel madly.

I looked at the second solution to the question mentioned earlier; the button drop down menu is greyed out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

You can enable it during the current session using the `xinput` command.  First of all, determine the ID of the device you want by running the `xinput list` command.  The output should look something like the following:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech USB Headset             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lite-On Technology Corp. ThinkPad USB Keyboard with TrackPoint    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Note the ID associated with the device you want to enable mouse wheel emulation for, and then run the following two commands:

```
xinput set-int-prop $ID "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 1
xinput set-int-prop $ID "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 8 2
```

The first command enables mouse wheel emulation, while the second sets it to activate when the middle (second) button is held.  You can disable wheel emulation by running:

```
xinput set-int-prop $ID "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 0
```

Comment: Eeeh, good for an ugly workaround... But I am looking for a more elegant solution because doing that isn't very convenient.

Comment: Well, you said that the `gpointing-device-settings` solution from the other question didn't help.  If this suggestion works for you but doesn't work in `gpointing-device-settings`, then the bug is in that app (it is basically just a front end for twiddling xinput properties).  You could follow that up with a bug report.

Comment: Also, the first answer in that question (an xorg.conf fragment) should do the trick (you should only need to set the `EmulateWheel` and `EmulateWheelButton` options though).

Comment: @James Henstridge I have just tried this, unfortunately this didn't work.

xinput set-int-prop $ID "Evdev Wheel Emulation" 8 1
Invalid format 1

So I assumed that I had to replace $ID with the ID of the pointing device, I did. Returned nothing. Repeated with the second one. Doesn't do anything.

Comment: You should be replacing $ID with the ID of the device you want to modify (for the set of devices on my system, 8 or 12 represent my mouse devices).  If you got the error "Invalid format 1", then you must have missed an argument and it was treating the 1 as the 3rd argument to `set-int-prop` instead of the 4th.

Comment: @James Henstridge well, it works but doesn't do what I want. I have to move the mouse to scroll, while I want it to base scrolling velocity on the difference between the starting drag position and the current drag position.

Answer (score 11):

I'm wondering if you are talking about 'Autoscrolling' in Firefox here? I don't know how to get the feature system-wide, but if you are looking to enable middle click scrolling in Firefox, go to Edit/Preferences/Advanced/General and click **Use autoscrolling**. (Note that if you middle-click while hovering on a link, you will open that link in a new tab).

If this is what you want, you should update the question to mention Firefox. If not, sorry I couldn't help.
[image: enable autoscrolling]

Comment: I don't use Firefox but this is exactly what I want.

Comment: The Autoscroll extension works for Chrome/Chromium. It's here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/occjjkgifpmdgodlplnacmkejpdionan

Comment: put that in the answer and I will upvote. I am afraid I can't accept this as the needed answer because it only solves this for particular applications.

Comment: it also doesn't do it as smooth as I would expect it to.

Comment: @nickguletskii just start using Firefox, you will love it.