# 2014 X1 Carbon , wifi toggle and clickpad

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, thinkpad

(ubuntu 14.04)

I have two questions, so I figured out to put them in one thread.

First is about adaptive keyboard, I noticed there is wifi toggle button which seems to do nothing, instead it should turn of wireless (as I have been told).

The second one is about clickpad. I know there has been numerous threads about it, but I probably need new one. 
I used instructions provided in [how to install driver for middle button clickpad scrolling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443642/how-to-install-driver-for-middle-button-clickpad-scrolling) this thread by T_Send, problem is, the touch is pretty wild. Taping left button sometimes reacts sometimes don't, middle button gets locked itself in scroll mode lots of time etc etc. Beside that, acceleration on the trackpoint is pretty slow. Also using clickpad fires lots of random clicks.

I tried tweaking setting in system settings, but it seems to be ignored. Even tap to click cannot be turned off.

I also tried this http://code.technically.us/post/50837506478/senistive-touchpads-and-ubuntu tutorial (alongside with T_Send solution), but it did nothing.

So what I want: Functioning trackpoint and clickpad with gestures support and natural scrolling if not then, trackpoint and clickpad if not then, just clickpad .

I am trying to find answer here because I know this problem affects all x40 thinkpads having same clickpad, and I suppose somebody here has some solution that works perfectly for them and can provide tutorial how they managed to do it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware BUG, returned while it was in warranty. It took them too long to repair so I just asked for money instead of laptop.

But I bought yoga, where it works.

So I got that going for me, which is nice.