# How to resolve dependency conflict for xserver-xorg-input-evdev

Tags: 14.04, drivers, package-management, thinkpad

I am trying to run a script provided by d3pd (updated by faf0) in an answer to [how to install driver for middle button clickpad scrolling](https://askubuntu.com/q/443642/491172). Unfortunately `sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-input-evdev` results in conflicting dependencies on my system (14.04.3 LTS).

Here's the output of `sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-input-evdev' (edit: changed to English)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed
 libegl1-mesa : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 7.11~1) but it is not going to be installed
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin : Depends: liboxideqtcore0 (= 1.11.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: liboxideqtquick0 (= 1.11.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5feedback5 : Depends: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for xserver-xorg-input-evdev could not be satisfied.
```

(btw. this is the first question I ask here. I am trying to be concise; pls let me know how to improve it!

Comment: Hmm, that works for me. Could you please run `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-input-evdev` and replace the error output in your question with an English version? This may make it easier for people to understand the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are specific evdev driver packages for each release. In my case it turns out that `sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-trusty` works just fine.

Though I'm running trusty it turns out that my system uses xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-vivid...