# Customise multitouch gestures on 16.04

Tags: touchpad, 16.04, multi-touch, make, makefile

I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe) but I get an error when I run `sudo make` and `sudo make install`. Any ideas on how to fix this error:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/me/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics'
Making all in include
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/me/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/me/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/include'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/me/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/src'
  CC       synaptics.lo
  CC       synproto.lo
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:630:0,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/os.h:53,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/misc.h:116,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/xf86str.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/xf86.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/xorg/xf86Xinput.h:54,
                 from synproto.h:36,
                 from synproto.c:24:
/usr/include/xorg/os.h:590:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__extension__’
 strndup(const char *str, size_t n);
 ^
Makefile:515: recipe for target 'synproto.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [synproto.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/me/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/src'
Makefile:511: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics'
Makefile:420: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came across this as well and have found the following:

https://github.com/felipejfc/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/issues/1

which then led to me finding this:

https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-input-synaptics/commit/?id=96e60a4ea242d2decf109835981ae186cc36f642

Although it is from a few years ago, it appears to be the same issue.

To summarise the two above links, to get the driver to work with the newer versions of glibc you must modify 3 files in the git repo that you cloned with the below command:

`$ git clone https://github.com/Chosko/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.git`

These files are all located in the src directory and are named as follows:

- eventcomm.h
- ps2comm.h
- synproto.h

You need to add `#include <xorg-server.h>` to the above files (I've put it above the others includes in each) and then re-run the following:

`$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --exec_prefix=/usr
$ make
$ sudo make install`

I don't know if this is the right way to go about it but it has worked for me!

Don't blame me if your touchpad doesn't work anymore though!

Comment: Thanks! It worked. The part you said i should add to those files already existed a few lines after the header comments, so I just commented it out and added it right at the top.

Comment: How do I now achieve all the 3 4 5 finger gestures?

Comment: I haven't got them working yet either so I can't help you on that one yet.

Comment: I was able to use 3 fingers to switch desktops horizontally. But that's only when I run the perl ~/xSwipe-master/xSwipe.pl command. I'll find a way to make the command run when I start up my laptop.

Comment: What laptop are you on? I didn't even manage to get xSwipe to work on my Dell XPS 13 (9350)

Comment: Acer Aspire E5 511