# Thinkpad P51 middle button page down doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

This middle button of scroll page down does not work in Ubuntu 16.04.

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thinkpad middle button scrolling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2557/thinkpad-middle-button-scrolling)

Comment: Also read related page(s) on [ThinkWiki about TrackPoint](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_configure_the_TrackPoint).

Comment: @N0rbert that question is 7 years old.. Not sure if is still valid. Also that wiki seem written when was Ubuntu 10..